# Alternate rankings for the same data

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, number-sequence

Jill and Suzie are given the same data set and instructed to rank each entry, but they are not allowed to rank the data using the same criteria.

Jill goes first and has no trouble at all. She easily evaluates her rankings and writes down her top 15:

> 90, 80, 40, 10, 70, 95, 75, 94, 35, 20, 15, 5, 73, 25, 55

Suzie takes what seems like the next best approach after Jill's and starts writing down her top rankings:

> 95, 90, 80, 70

But after only the first 4 she runs into a problem. Thinking on her feet, she tweaks her method and is able to continue:

> 10, 40, 74, 94, 35

But after 9 entries, she encounters another problem, and this time she's really stuck. Unable to determine a tiebreaker, she declares a 3-way tie for 10th place:

> 69 / 20 / 15

She then continues with 13th and 14th place:

> 75, 55

But she's forced to declare a tie again at 15th:

> 64 / 81

Jill gloats smugly at Suzie, having clearly chosen the superior ranking method. Suzie knows she had the more difficult task, but she feels the data they were given was partly to blame.

### What data were Jill and Suzie ranking? What method did each use, and why does Suzie feel that the data was partly to blame for her failure?

---

**Hint #1:** The data table Jill and Suzie were using had three entries that were broken down into two rows each (unlike the majority of the entries, which were each entered on one row). The girls treated each row of data as an individual data point and ranked them accordingly. However, if their data table had presented with each of these entries as only one row of (the equivalent combined) data, `84` would have ranked 15th for Jill and 9th for Suzie.

**Hint #2:** The [trivia](/questions/tagged/trivia) in this puzzle is specific to the US.

Comment: Suzie's rankings have either 13 entries (counting each tie—at 10 and 13 respectively—as one) or 16 entries (4 + 5 + 3 + 2 + 2)

Comment: @question_asker, Suzie has ranked a total of 16 entries, but she has only awarded 13 unique ranks due to the ties.

Comment: OK cool, just making sure I wasn't miscounting, thank you!

Comment: Added a hint for the one week mark.

Comment: Thanks! I like this one, it's tough. One question: "The data table...had three entries that were broken down into two rows each" - that makes it sound like there are only six things being ranked, total - how does that work?

Comment: @question_asker: Sorry for the confusion. To clarify, the data table had significantly more rows than those that are ranked. The hint refers to three *unique* entries which were further broken down into to rows *unlike the other entries*.

Comment: @Josh I am confused about whether those numbers in the girls' rankings are the data itself, or just identifiers for the rows for the corresponding data. For example, we could have a unique_id column which has the numbers in the rankings ("90, 80, 40, ..." in Jill's case), but there can also be other columns we don't see in the question. Did the girls' ranking methods only use the numbers we see in their rankings? And do the same numbers correspond to the same entry? (I.e. Does 90 in Jill's list correspond to the same data entry as the 90 in Suzie's list?)

Comment: @SpiritFryer, you are asking a very good question, part of which was intentionally left vague. </hint> However, I will clarify that both girls are definitely using columns of information that are not presented in the puzzle to arrive at their rankings and that their ranked entries do correspond to one another (90, Jill's #1, is the same entry as 90, Suzie's #2).

Comment: [Post 1/2] The numbers in the rankings definitely have more significance that just being "unique identifiers" between the girls' lists, otherwise there'd be infinite possibilities as to what the data is. So I'm inclined to think that the numbers in the rankings should indicate the kind of data we are dealing with, which then should help find out the methods the girls used. Even then, I think one can come up with an infinite number of methods (as there are an infinite number of possibilities as to the hidden data columns' contents), but I feel like there should be two/three simple ones.

Comment: [2/2] What really bugs me is that since we don't know how many hidden data columns there are, the girls could have used the same approach but on different columns. The first thing I thought of was that there are 3 hidden data columns. Jill sorted by the 1st one, and the numbers happened to be unique. Suzie sorted by the 2nd one, but there were duplicates, so she broke ties by sorting by the 3rd one, which turned out to have duplicates too. Just now I realized that using this method their rankings wouldn't be representative as they don't take into account all of the data (just certain columns).

Comment: @SpiritFryer, you are on the right track. Figuring out the significance of the numbers each entry is listed by is probably the biggest step of the puzzle, after which point the rest should be relatively simple. As to your second post, I would argue that any columns they didn't use to rank the data are irrelevant. I should think it's obvious that they are ranking *real* data, not something I made up on the spot, and I should think there are very few (if any) things in the real world with a definitive complete list of data points. All you need to figure out are the ones they *did* use.

Comment: "I would argue that any columns they didn't use to rank the data are irrelevant" Ah yes, you're right actually. If I'm sorting (or ranking) a list of files by their sizes, then I don't necessarily care about when they were last modified, for instance. (Though I will need a way to tiebreak files of the same size.)

Comment: Added a second hint. They will keep coming every few days if no one solves it.

Comment: At first I was thinking it might be highways or freeways, but I'm not familiar with 94 or 73.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Jill has ranked

> the US Interstate Highways

by

> length.

Suzie has ranked them by

> number of states passed through, and then by age as a tiebreaker.

The problem is that

> some Interstates pass through the same number of states, and were formed in the same year. Because these are the only statistics provided other than the length, Suzie has no other way to order them.

Comment: Correct! She could also have been frustrated at having just the year instead of the exact date, but that part of the question was bound to have more than one answer.

Comment: What is the problem Suzie runs into after the fourth one?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain After the fourth one, there were ties by number of states, which is when she had to add age as a tiebreaker.

Comment: Oh, right.  Thanks.  You explained that in your answer; my brain just wasn't quite working right.

Answer (score 1):

It could be temperature based on latitude (North to South) and longitude (east to west).

Comment: Can you explain why you think thay? Plain answers are usually deleted.

Comment: If that's the case, why was it so much easier for Jill? What tweak did Suzie make after ranking her top 4?

Comment: @Deusovi It is a potential response - that demonstrate that ranking of on value based on other values may result different ranking.

Comment: @Josh there might be a "better" answer but assuming Suzie elected to use longitude and some values had the same longitude, than applying latitude gets this ranking.

Comment: My point was that this question is multi-faceted and your answer does not explain itself to the degree requested. I am open to answers other than the one I intended if they answer the question *completely* and without any holes in logic. Even with your additional explanation, you haven't answered what data they were ranking, what method Jill used, or why Suzie in part blamed the data for her failure.